# What does "squeeze along" mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, american-english

> It was not intended that we should have such a hard time getting a
> living, that we should just manage to **squeeze along**, to get together a
> few comforts, to spend about all of our time making a living instead
> of making a life.
>
> Marden, Orison Swett. Pushing to the Front (p. 466).

Comment: Did you look up [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squeeze)? It has *to exert pressure* and *to force one's way* and also alludes to *cause economic hardship to* etc. They possibly squeeze the most value from a dollar that they can too. Nice choice of word.

Comment: It's probably related to [squeeze by](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/squeeze+by) meaning "To manage to accomplish something by very narrowly overcoming some difficulty." *Squeeze* conveys the sense of only just making it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, "squeeze" and "along" are two separate words, not a phrasal verb.

"Squeeze" has the meaning [force one's way](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squeeze), which Weather Vane pointed out in a comment. This meaning of "squeeze" is almost always accompanied by an adverbial of direction

"Along" is such an adverb, meaning ["forward" or "on"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/along)

So your quote means, "*...that we should just manage to **force our way forward**...*".